# Нужно ли прописывать в manifest`е css файл для popup.html? Файл лежит в корне, но никак не подключается

Tags: html5, google-chrome, chrome-extension

Не подключается файл .css из файла popup.html в chrome extension, может его необходимо прописать в manifest?

Answer (score 1):

Из руководства Google:

> If your content script's code should always be injected, register it in the extension manifest using the content_scripts field, as in the following example.

```js
{
  "name": "My extension",
  ...
  "content_scripts": [{
    "matches": ["http://www.google.com/*"],
    "css": ["mystyles.css"],
    "js": ["jquery.js", "myscript.js"]
  }],
  ...
}
```

Comment: Да, так подключается css для элементов, которые динамически создаются при работе content_script, popup же  не инъекцируется в код страницы

Comment: Для расширений Firefox достаточно подключить стили и скрипт в самом html-документе (popup.html).